# No aparece datos en la transición Genexus

Tags: genexus

Alguien que me pueda ayudar, tengo un procedimiento en Genexus donde estoy leyendo los datos de un excel y esos mismos antes me aparecían con normalidad en la transcición clientes que le estaba llamando al procedimiento (y se estan cargando correctamente en la base de datos los registros) pero hoy que quise leerle otro excel al cambiarle las columnas y demas le lee le carga en la base de datos pero no se muestra en la transición alguien sabe que puede ser porfavor

Answer (score 0):

Desde la transacción llamas a un procedimiento que carga datos en la base?
Si es así, no vas a ver automáticamente los datos a menos que vuelvas a llamar a la transacción en modo update.
Lo normal es llamar a los procs que leen excels y escriben en la base desde un webpanel, y luego desde un WW (Work with / trabajar con) accedes a los registros por medio de las transacciones.